# What to call a function that splits lists?

Tags: haskell, f#, functional-programming, sml, split

I want to write a function that splits lists into sublists according to what items satisfy a given property `p`.  My question is what to call the function.   I'll give examples in Haskell, but the same problem would come up in F# or ML.

```
split :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]  --- split lists into list of sublists
```

The sublists, concatenated, are the original list:

```
concat (split p xss) == xs
```

Every sublist satisfies the `initial_p_only p` property, which is to say (A) the sublist begins with an element satisfying `p`—and is therefore not empty, and (B) no other elements satisfy `p`:

```
initial_p_only :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
initial_p_only p [] = False
initial_p_only p (x:xs) = p x && all (not . p) xs
```

So to be precise about it,

```
all (initial_p_only p) (split p xss)
```

If the very first element in the original list does not satisfy `p`, split fails.

This function needs to be called something other than `split`.  **What should I call it??**

Comment: groupBy doesn't seem quite right. groupAt might work.

Comment: I love how you wrote a formal specification without an implementation.

Comment: Sorry if this comes a bit late, but I believe your representation is wrong. "Make illegal states unrepresentable". What you should return is a list of `(a, [a])`. And your input should probably be `(a, [a])` as well, but for a slightly different reason (beware confusions). If this is a recurrent theme in your problem domain, it may also be worth it to newtype `PAndList` and `PAndNotPList` to differentiate those two types.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe the function you're describing is `breakBefore` from the [list-grouping](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/list-grouping) package.

`Data.List.Grouping`: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/list-grouping/0.1.1/doc/html/Data-List-Grouping.html

```
ghci> breakBefore even [3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5,3,5,8,9,7,9,3,2,3,8,4,6,2,6]
[[3,1],[4,1,5,9],[2],[6,5,3,5],[8,9,7,9,3],[2,3],[8],[4],[6],[2],[6]]
```

Comment: +1 for not only giving a name, but an already-existing implementation of the function.

Comment: Terrifying.  My code has already been written.  Thanks kindly.

Comment: I don't like plain variants of `break` since `break` itself produces a tuple and not a list. Maybe `breaksBefore` except the plural is too subtle. `unfoldBreaks` is a pretty literal name.

Comment: `breakBefore` doesn't seem to exactly match your specification because `breakBefore` doesn't require that the first element of the first grouping in the result satisfies the given predicate, but the specification does require this (otherwise the function should fail--that's what the specification says).

Answer (score 2):

I quite like some name based on the term "break" as adamse suggests. There are quite a few possible variants of the function. Here is what I'd expect (based on the naming used in F# libraries).

A function named just `breakBefore` would take an element before which it should break:

```
breakBefore :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [[a]]
```

A function with the `With` suffix would take some kind of function that directly specifies when to break. In case of brekaing this is the function `a -> Bool` that you wanted:

```
breakBeforeWith :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
```

You could also imagine a function with `By` suffix would take a *key selector* and break when the key changes (which is a bit like `group by`, but you can have multiple groups with the same key):

```
breakBeforeBy :: Eq k => (a -> k) -> [a] -> [[a]]
```

I admit that the names are getting a bit long - and maybe the only function that is really useful is the one you wanted. However, F# libraries seem to be using this pattern quite consistently (e.g. there is `sort`, `sortBy` taking key selector and `sortWith` taking comparer function).

Perhaps it is possible to have these three variants for more of the list processing functions (and it's quite good idea to have some consistent naming pattern for these three types).

Comment: I simply named mine `break : ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list * 'a list`